Indoor 10 feet tall avocado tree I tall needs to be cut
I started this tree from a pit 42 years ago. I am very attached to it. It is now a tree with bark and has 3 trunks and is really too big. Can I start a new one from a shoot growing out of one of its trunk and if yes, would I put the stem in water or in earth right away?

I think the correct answer is "move house to somewhere with higher ceilings"

If you have any shoots low down the trunk (unlikely given the typical avocado I've seen in a pot) you could top the tree there and make use of the existing roots rather than trying to get a shoot to root. Or perhaps cut two trunks and see if it sends up any new shoots, then cut the third if it does. I've been spared the personal itch to grow one, so I don't know how these would work specifically with avocados, but they are general tree methods.

Check the colour of the bark. If brown, the branch is very mature and unlikely to be of use for cuttings. I have heard that if the trunk is brown, then the avacado tree is resistant to frost and sunburn.

Theoretically it is possible to grow an avocado from a cutting - however my attempts were unsuccessful.  In fairness I knew a lot less then I know now and probably left on to much foliage.
I've not had the opportunity to do this (I was going to, but cows killed my tree first) if you want to create a new plant from a shoot growing out of its trunk, I'd try air layering.
Air layering is the process of removing a section of outer bark (typically around 1" long around the whole diameter) of the shoot while leaving the inner core and then packing soil around the stripped bark.  I don't know that its necessary but a lot of guides suggest painting rooting hormone on the stripped area. This encourages the plant to send out roots so it can get nutrients, while still allowing water to get to the leaves so the plant does not die.   Somewhat counterintuitively you need to ensure the green bit immediately under the bark is also removed.    Once the new roots have grown into the soil you can sever the branch and plant the new tree (If you google Air layering there are lots of videos and explanations of it - including specifically for avocados).

I don't have experience doing that in water, but I would suggest that you try the cutting in soil.  You have nothing to lose,
Try several cuttings at once in different conditions.  The best chance is to take a cutting of a new shoot.  Take off the bottom third to half of the leaves and stick it in soil.  Keep the soil moist.
